# setTransform stage method, Easeljs

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I'm trying to resize a canvas using EaselJS each time I click on a link. I'm doing this:

```
function resizeCanvas(){
    console.log("Resizing...")
    stage.setTransform(0,0,1.5,1.5,1,1,1,1,1);

    stage.update();
}
```

But it seems that it is only resized one time. The documentation says that setTransform returns a  DisplayObject: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_setTransform

Does it mean that It returns an stage object that I should asign to my old stage variable? How could I resize it properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTransform()` `SETs` the transform-properties to the given values, it doesn't `add` it, a way to zoom further would be to save the transform-values in separate variables/object and increase those before calling the `setTransform()` with it.

But if you just want to zoom the Stage and don't want to save the values separatly you could do something like:

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    stage.scaleX *= 1.5;
    stage.scaleY *= 1.5;
    // but beware this is exponetial, maybe you want to use this linear method:
    // stage.scaleX/Y += 0.5;

    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many display object methods return "this" so the methods can be chained, something like:

`container.addChild(new Bitmap(src).set({alpha:0.5}).setTransform(100,200));`